# SQL Statement on Logstash JDBC | How do i filter only on the today's inserted rows?

Tags: logstash

In my oracle database i have a column insert_date. On elasticsearch i want to index only the events that are inserted today.
Here is my conf:

```
       jdbc {
            type => "D"
            jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xxx.xx.xx.xx:1521/xx"
            jdbc_driver_class => "Java::oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
            jdbc_user => "xxx"
            jdbc_password => "xx"
            statement  => "select * from mytable where insert_date = TRUNC(SYSDATE)  order by insert_date desc"
            schedule => "0 * * * * *"
            clean_run => true
            last_run_metadata_path => "/data/application/.logstash_jdbc_last_run"
            }
```

I run this script but keep getting an error on logstash.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try the below query.

```
Select * from mytable where insert_date > 
sysdate-24/24 order by insert_date
```